# Why Bond(graph theory) is non-empty

Tags: graph-theory

According to Diestel, bond is defined as the minimal non-empty element of cut-space at [page 25](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch1.pdf).

He explain the non-empty condition in the difinition of a bond bites only if G is disconnected.

What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of bond :

> A minimal non-empty cut in $G$ is a *bond*

Then your question is related to the footnote $11$ :

> The empty set of edges is a cut only if the graph is disconnected.

Therefore if the graph is connected, any cut is non-empty, and the definition of bonds is just *minimal cut in $G$*, the condition non-empty is useless as this can never happen.